# query from fusion table to select rows with the most recent date

Tags: database, google-fusion-tables

I am a newbie of javascript and fusion tables and I am setting up a project which collects and elaborates data into a google spreadsheet and then submit them to a fusion table database. The data archived have to be retrieved back into the spreadsheet with SELECT query to be used for further elaboration or to be updated and submitted again into the fusion table.

the structure of the record to be inserted and retrieved includes the following field:

field1, field2, field3, etc.

where field1 is a date/time fiedl and field2 represents a list of Countries

The query I would like to create should retrieve the subset of records including the most recent date record (field1) for each country (field2). I tried to build a SELECT query with a WHERE clause but it doesn't work. I read somewhere that this kind of problems could be solved by using a self join but I am not sure it is possible to make this kind of join in fusion tables and I don't know how to proceed.

Can anybody give me some hints or suggestions to find a solution?

Thanks in advance

Luigi

Comment: field2 is a column containing a list of 131 countries

Comment: by the way, the column can contain each country repeated a multiple number of times